# How to add a delay to vim highlight?

Tags: vim

Suppose I have the following lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
highlight TrailingWhitespace ctermfg=blue
match TrailingWhitespace /[ ]\+$/
```

How do I add a delay to the highlighting so that spaces between words I type will not turn blue instantly?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, however there are people arround here who could answer this for sure. But most people just use light-gray listchars type `:h lcs` for more. What i could give you, is a function which deletes trailing whitespace's automatically on save, let me know if you are interested, then i will point you to some SO questions about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually solved by **adapting the search pattern in insert mode** so that is doesn't match when the cursor is at the end of the line; i.e. when you're still typing stuff. A common implementation can be found on [this Vim Tips Wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces):

```
:au InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
:au InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
```

There is no "delayed highlight" in Vim.

#### Plugin recommendation

If you're looking for a robust implementation and don't mind installing a plugin, have a look at my [ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966). It leaves the `:match` command for other uses, can be switched on/off, and supports exceptions for certain filetypes, all configurable. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)